# FileInterceptor and Body Issue in NestJS (upload a file and data in a request)

Tags: postman, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I have the following controller :

```js
createCollection(
    @UploadedFile() file,
    @Body() createCollectionDto: CreateCollectionDto,
    @GetUser() user: User,
  ): Promise<Collection> {
    this.logger.verbose(
      `User "${
        user.username
      }" creating a new collection. Data: ${JSON.stringify(
        createCollectionDto,
      )} of "${user.username}"`,
    );
    if (file) {
      return this.collectionService.createCollection(
        createCollectionDto,
        user,
        file,
      );
    } else {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException('File needed');
    }
  }
```

I need to upload a file and In the same query give some data.
[image: data I want to give to the api]

Because I want to upload a file, I set up Postman like this:
[image: second setup of postman]

**First Question** : How can I send the **file** along with the **data** showed in picture n°1 ?

I searched another tool for API requests and I found [Postwoman](https://postwoman.io/)

Here is the config I used : 
[image: Postwoman config]

But the response is always the same: It doesn't detects the data. (i.e. `{ name: foo, color: bar}` )

[image]

**Second Question** : How can I solve this issue ? Is it possible to put data along a file ? If it is possible how can I achieve that in NestJS ?

Thank you very much for reading my question :) Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're pretty close. To upload a file and extra properties in a single request in Postman, you *need* to choose `form-data` and *not* `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

[image: Screenshot of Postman]

And here is a simple NestJS controller that shows that you can get all of the data:

```js
import { Body, Controller, Post, UploadedFile, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';

@Controller('upload-stack-overflow')
export class UploadStackOverflowController {

  @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  uploadSingleFileWithPost(@UploadedFile() file, @Body() body) {
    console.log(file);
    console.log(body.firstName);
    console.log(body.favoriteColor);
  }
}
```

Comment: I found out the problem thanks, as always it's a stupid error : I expected 'image' but in postman I gave the name 'file'

Comment: How to upload data and file in same request in database using nestjs. can you help me with this please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849722/need-to-upload-file-in-postgres-database-using-typeorm-nestjs

Comment: @PaulMest do you have a solution for nested file handling. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72490730/nestjs-multiple-file-upload-with-extra-properties